# np.where for string containing specific word

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to write code that adds value in a new column depending on the condition. For example, I have df, it has sentences as values. I want to add a new column, called "Marketing" if the string in the certain column contains the word "Marketing". Example:

```
df['Marketing'] =np.where(df['Funding_%'] == 'Marketing', "marketing", 'rest')
```

The problem is that expression above works only with an exact match, not if a string contains the word.

Data Sample (with error where all rows are marked as marketing):
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I am getting all rest: `np.where(df['Funding_%'].astype(str).str.contains('Marketing'), "marketing", 'rest')`

Comment: please always check your columns dtype. `.str` works on object type columns.

Comment: That's in your grade column right?

Comment: Yes, correct, however it is just first rows as you can understand. Type is object...

Comment: right, astype works wonders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the string with the substring so use `.str.contains()`

Your example does string matching with another string that's why getting the issue. You need to find whther the substring exist in the string or not so use that.

```
df['Marketing'] =np.where(df['Funding_%'].str.contains('Marketing', regex= True), "marketing", 'rest')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! This code does not work. It marks all rows as "marketing". Maybe because string is in Hebrew? df['Marketing'] =np.where(df['Funding_%'].str.contains('מאחוז', regex= True), "marketing", 'rest') . Should not be the case, because exact match in hebrew works just fine

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov: Can you post your sample data?

Comment: added. This is after I added your code. Thanks)

Comment: @MayyaLihovodov: you said hebrew?? but your data doesnt contain that .

Comment: Sure it contains) row #4